# Procmon command line does not save filtered output

Tags: windows, procmon, process-monitor

I am using procmon command line.

```
procmon.exe /Quiet /Minimized /Openlog C:\Python27\code2\logs.pml /LoadConfig C:\Python27\code2\pmc.pmc /SaveAs C:\Python27\code2\output.csv
```

After running the above command, the procmon UI shows filtered events but the saved file - output.csv contains all the events.

Is there an option to save the filtered output via cmd? If not, is there a way to copy the output to cmd?

Comment: Did you enable "Drop filtered events" in the saved config file?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers I figured out the solution. I have 1 more query. Is there a way to load .pmf file instead of entire .pmc file?

Comment: I honestly have no idea. From the two of us, I'm the one that's learning the most from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I was missing the /SaveApplyFilter option. It's strange I did not find a quick reference on forums either.
So adding

```
/SaveApplyFilter /SaveAs C:\code2\testing2.csv
```

achieved the desired result.

Also, since I was using existing log file, there is no need to use "Drop Filtered Events" while saving the configuration file.

In case you are capturing logs and want to save them with filters applied, you could enable "Drop Filtered Events" to capture only the required events.